# Passing variables between classes in Java

Tags: java, class, variables, paintcomponent

I have two separate classes: `GameOfLife.java` and `Grid.java`, the latter of which has a `paintComponent` method. In `GameOfLife.java`, I have a constantly changing variable, `toRepaint`, that I need to access in `Grid.java`.

Here is a section of `GameOfLife.java` where I set `toRepaint`:

```
if (an==0) {
    toRepaint = (String)c.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println(toRepaint);
}
main.repaint();
```

Here is where I need to access that variable in `Grid.java`:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics ob) {
    super.paintComponent(ob);
    Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D) ob;
    String rep = ??? //This variable should equal the value of toRepaint
}
```

How can I access this variable?

Comment: define  an interface ....

Comment: create an object and access it or extend the `GameOfLife.java` and access directly..As per @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ interface or abstract class will be good choice.

Comment: What is the relationship between these two classes?

Comment: I use `grid.java` to paint graphics for a GUI interface.

Comment: is the variable in your code `main` an instance of `Grid` ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To do this, you must make the variable you want to access in another class a public class variable (also known as a field):

```
public class GameOfLife{
    public static String toRepaint;

    public void yourMethod() {
        //set value, do stuff here
    }
}
```

And then in Grid.java, you access the class variable using dot syntax:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics ob) {
    super.paintComponent(ob);
    Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D) ob;
    String rep = GameOfLife.toRepaint;
}
```

**HOWEVER**

This is not the best way to do it, but is by far the simplest. In order to follow object-oriented programming we would add the following accessor method to our `GameOfLife` class:

```
public static String getToRepaint(){
    return toRepaint;
}
```

and change our variable declaration to:

```
private static String toRepaint;
```

In our Grid class, we instead call the method that accesses the `toRepaint` variable:

```
    String rep = GameOfLife.getToRepaint();
```

This is the heart of object oriented programming, and although it seems redundant, can be quite helpful later on and will help keep code much neater.

Comment: `GameOfLife.toRepaint` will not work, unless you make `toRepaint` a `static` variable, which would be very bad in its own right. Likewise for `GameOfLife.getToRepaint()`

Comment: You are a genius. Like Erwin said however, I did have to make toReprint a static variable!! Thank you both!!!

Comment: You're right about the static, I will fix that. However, from what appears to be a fairly simple application, I don't see how it would be necessary to create another interface if they only have to classes

Comment: You are missing **which would be very bad in its own right**

Comment: really? static method wins?? :)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Not in real life

Comment: Use static only if you are certain there is one and only one copy of that member in the class. It may seem to work now, but when you have more than one instance of `GameOfLife`, you will see the problem.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion will be :

1. Define an interface:

```
public interface IGame{
    String getName();
}
```

2. make the GameOfLife class to implement that interface

and override the method like

```
@Override
public String getName(){
       return rep;
    }
```

3. the Grid.java needs the reference, either pass that in the constructor or use setters getters...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics ob) {
    super.paintComponent(ob);
    Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D) ob;
    String rep = myInterface.getName();
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused...Where specifically do I define the interface?

Comment: you can define that as another file in the same package